# responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)

Tags: swift, api, alamofire

I have a API with post method and following is the code for it

```
func addScheduleService() {
      let parameter = ["start_time":"06:00","end_time":"09:00","schedule_date":"07/23/2020","schedule_id":"0"]
                      
                      print("parameter is",parameter)
        
       let header: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/json","x-token": self.token!]

 AF.request(mainURL+URLS.addschedule.rawValue, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
        .responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let json):
                print("value is",json)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("error is",error)}
            }
        }
```

The response in the postman is as follows:

[image]

The output from the code is responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)

What could be the error?

Comment: Did you try with same header/body parameters you wrote in postman? For example `end_time` parameters are  different. Also try with `.responseData` instead of `.responseJSON`

Comment: You mean the order of the parameters?

Comment: No. It is `"end_time":"10:00"` in screenshot, but `"end_time":"09:00"` in code. There should be invalid Json response for your request (empty, error message etc). So there is a failure when trying to serialize the response.

Comment: that it just a string...how to serialise it then?

Comment: If you need to parse a json you need a valid json response. Did you try `.responseData` or `.responseString` instead of `.responseJSON` as i mentioned? also add the response to your question.

Answer (score 4):

`.inputDataNilOrZeroLength` means you got an empty response without a 204 or 205 response code, so Alamofire considers the response invalid (empty bodies are only valid for 204 or 205 responses). If this is expected, you'll need to add the expected status code to the list of acceptable empty response codes in `responseDecodable`:

```swift
AF.request(...).responseDecodable(of: YourType.self,
                                  emptyResponseCodes: [200, 204, 205]) { response in

}
```

Comment: Okay will try....but im not using any model for this...

Comment: You can pass the same parameter to `responseJSON`, but I recommend creating a `Decodable` type for your response.

Comment: The response has only two values.How to have a decodable type for this API?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might have a look to this answer -> GitHub [Alamofire-responseSerializationFailed](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2811#issuecomment-490370829)

It looks like the server response has an empty body, so Alamofire will receive it, as it is.

Alamofire will look after the result `code`, and will find `200`, but with an empty body. And may not be considered as valid, for an empty response.

Go with number 1 if you can act on server side.

1 - Change server response to proper `204` - empty

2 - Create your own DataResponseSerializer:

```
let dataResponseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer(emptyResponseCodes: [200, 204, 205]) // Default is [204, 205]
manager.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        /// ...
    }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: ep.s3.virginiaBucketUrl, method: .post, headers: headers)
    .response(responseSerializer: dataResponseSerializer) { response in
        switch response.result {
            case .failure(let error):
                // ...
            case .success(let value):
                // ...
        }
    }
```